# send parameter from request through json

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

How can I resend parameter I received from servlet to servlet using json.

Here's what I mean, I am using this way to pass parameters to servlet

```
<a href="StudentManagementServlet?page=${page}&isActivated=${isActivated}" >
```

but now, I wanna make it using json, so How can I reach `${page}` and `${isActivated}` from json?

Comment: JSON is an object literal syntax, so there is no way to reach `${page}` "from JSON". Please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to enhance my code, and want to use json when I click on anchor to call servlet and send some parameters defined at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP parses the page before it sends it to the client, so you can use the ${variables} anywhere in the code, including inline in javascript.

To store them as a JavaScript object:

```
var obj = { page: ${page}, isActivated: ${isActivated} };
```

To store them as a JSON Object:

```
var jsonObject = { "page" : "${page}", "isActivated": "${isActivated}" };
```

Now, if you want to send it to a different servlet, you'll need to attach the JSON objectto a POST request to that servlet.

Unfortunately you can't do POST requests from an anchor tag, you'll need to do either an AJAX call or do a form submit with the jsonObject as one of the values.

Comment: when I make like this in servlet request.getParameter("page") , it returns null , I remove the single qoutes it works correctly.

Comment: @Alaa Like this? { "page" : "${page}", "isActivated": "${isActivated}" }